# Как исправить ошибку self referencing loop detected при создании json-файла?

Tags: c#, json, winforms, visual-studio

Необходимо создать файл `json` со всеми значениями `List<Control>`.
`List<Control>` принимает свои значения в методе `GetPictureElements()`, код метода:

```
public List<Control> GetPicureElements()
        {
            List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
            foreach (Control control in pictureBoxMain.Controls)
            {
                list.Add(control);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Далее создан класс для хранения полученного списка:

```
namespace projectws
{
    [Serializable]
    public class EL
    {
        private List<Control> _el;
        [DataMember]
        public List<Control> El
        {
            get => _el;
            set => _el = value;
        }
        public EL(List<Control> el)
        {
            El = el;
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка "Self referencing loop detected for property 'Owner' with type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'. Path 'El[0].AccessibilityObject'." возникает в коде создания `json` файла:

```
private void buttonSaveVersion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var el = new EL(GetPicureElements());
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(el); //ошибка тут
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("test.json", json);
        }
```

Примечание: `List<Control>` имеет некоторое нестатичное количество элементов `Label`, добавляемых пользователем в `PictureBox`, соответсвенно ошибку выдаёт первый ([0]) полученный из списка `Label`

Comment: я вам, вроде как, объяснил схему всё в комментарии к предыдущему такому же вопросу, могли сразу там задать уточняющий вопрос

Comment: Так вроде-же [в настройках](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) можно указать игнорирование циклических ссылок? Например, как в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8711702/3129992).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Контролы сериализовать не получится. Создавайте структуры данных для сериализации, атрибуты здесь тоже не нужны.

```
public List<string> GetLabelsTexts()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    foreach (Label label in pictureBoxMain.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    {
        result.Add(label.Text);
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
List<string> items = GetLabelsTexts();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
File.WriteAllText("test.json", json);
```

---

Можно хоть с координатами

```
public class LabelInfo
{
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

```
public List<LabelInfo> GetLabelsInfo()
{
    List<LabelInfo> result = new List<LabelInfo>();
    foreach (Label label in pictureBoxMain.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    {
        result.Add(new LabelInfo
        {
            Text = label.Text,
            Location = label.Location
        });
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
List<LabelInfo> items = GetLabelsInfo();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
File.WriteAllText("test.json", json);
```

---

Десериализовать обратно так же легко

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
List<LabelInfo> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LabelInfo>>(json);
pictureBoxMain.Controls.Clear();
foreach (LabelInfo info in items)
{
    pictureBoxMain.Controls.Add(new Label
    {
        Text = info.Text,
        Location = info.Location
    });
}
```